# Pass object data from controller to Partial View in MVC C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have class CourseInstanceModel and in Feed class I am reading all courses followed by LINQ query to get all those courses whose URL field in database in empty and then passing back to controller; storing in object effectedCourseInstances . The new list I need to display to page (View) before user accept or decline.

I am struggling to pass effectedCourseInstances to partial view from controller ????

### Feed Class

```
public List<CourseInstanceModel> ProcessAllCoursesApplicationURL(CourseApplicationsURLFeed_Model _obj)
    {
        using(var _uof = new Courses_UnitOfWork())
        {
          var  ListOfCoursesInstances = _uof.CourseInstances_Repository.GetAll();

          var _listOfCoursesWithoutURL = (from b in ListOfCoursesInstances 
                                           where b.ApplicationURL == null
                                           select b).ToList();
          return _listOfCoursesWithoutURL;
        }

 }
```

### Controller class

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ProcessCourseApplicationURL()
    {
        return PartialView("ProcessCourseApplicationURL_Partial");
    }


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProcessCourseApplicationURL(CourseApplicationsURLFeed_Model obj)
    { 
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
              _effectedCourseInstances = _coursesServices.ProcessAllCoursesApplicationURL(obj);
            }
        }
        catch (DataException ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable To Process Courses Application URL from CID DB" + ex);
        }
        return PartialView("CourseApplicationURLTest_Partial"); 
        ????? need to pass effectedCourseInstances data to Partial View?????
    } //end
```

### View

```
@model CID_App.DAL.Model.CourseInstanceModel

read effectedCourseInstances of CourseInstanceModel class here ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the model to the PartialView function. The view will also need to accept a list of `CourseInstanceModel`

## View

```
@model List<CID_App.DAL.Model.CourseInstanceModel>
```

## Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProcessCourseApplicationURL(CourseApplicationsURLFeed_Model obj)
    { 
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
              _effectedCourseInstances = _coursesServices.ProcessAllCoursesApplicationURL(obj);
            }
        }
        catch (DataException ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable To Process Courses Application URL from CID DB" + ex);
        }
        return PartialView("CourseApplicationURLTest_Partial", _effectedCourseInstances); 
    }
```

Comment: I am getting following error                                                                    The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CID_App.DAL.Model.CourseInstanceModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'CID_App.DAL.Model.CourseInstanceModel'.

Comment: You changed the view to accept the List? 
_effectedCourseInstances is going to be of type List<CourseInstanceModel> based on the definition in your question

Answer (score 0):

@toxic :View is just for presenting your Data Model (return from controller) & in your case you are rendering List data type of your model so view will be accept only List.
@Oliver is right ,thanks for sharing your knowledge.